# VS 2012 Blank Siverlight on Lightswitch Debug

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-lightswitch

I've been playing around with Lightswitch (c#) on Visual Studio 2012. The project I was developing  was working great until today. When I click debug, the Silverlight screen opens, I get the Loading... message and then nothing. A blank screen.

There was nothing obvious in the output. Here's the last three lines:

> The program '[3312] SLLauncher.exe: Silverlight' has exited with code
>   0 (0x0).
>
> The program '[5668] VslsHost.exe: Managed (v4.0.30319)' has exited
>   with code 0 (0x0).
>
> VslsHost is using port 50446.

I've created a brand new 'hello world' project and get the same response.

Also I've noticed the square symbol next to the Visual Studio title on any VS message boxes which was not there yesterday (well I'm pretty sure).

[image: example of square after Visual Studio message header]

And every time I open VS2012 I'm asked if I want the following program to make changes to Windows : devenv.exe. This seems benign, but I wasn't asked yesterday. I've tried restarting the PC with no difference.

The project I was working on works fine on VS2012 on my laptop. Also Lightswitch works fine using my VS2010 on the same PC.

Any ideas? Reinstall??

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could try doing a **repair** on VS 2012, before uninstalling/reinstalling.

Did you install any other programs etc on the machine? Did you get a Silverlight update prompt, or anything like that? *Something* has to have changed, it's just a matter of tracking down what it was.

The repair is the first thing that I'd try. I've never seen, nor heard of that square appearing in the title bar of message boxes, so that's also very strange.

Answer (score 1):

I've had the little square since I installed VS 2012, on Windows 8 x64. Not sure what's causing it, but that's typically because the font doesn't support a character.

I'd bet that MS is using an ellipsis character there instead of "...", and for some reason the current font isn't picking it up.